# How to "accept" nested class object instances by running a custom method before to store those?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model, attributes

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.1.0 and I would like to run a `:reject_if` method (*as* described in the [official documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html) related to the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` method in the "One-to-many" association section) on class object instances "*at all*" (that is, to run the `:reject_if` method *not* on attributes - as made in the linked documentation - but on records that should be "subsequently" stored in the database). In few words, I would like to reject\filter some nested model\class object instances that should be stored in the database by running a custom method on those instances.

For example, if I have the following:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article,

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article
end
```

I would like to make something like this (the following code does not work):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :article,

  # Note: by using 'article' in the block I (would like to) refer to class
  # object instances
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :article, :reject_if => { |article| article.can_be_created? }
end

class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  def can_be_created?
    true if user.has_authorization?
  end
end
```

**Is it possible? If so, how can I make that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a method that returns a boolean, and give the method name as a symbol to `:reject_if`, eg:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :article, :reject_if => :article_uncreateable?

def article_uncreateable?
  !Article.new(article_attributes).can_be_created?
end
```

Comment: Agreed with Jim's comment here... Just use validations on the article model.